# Virtual inheritance and function members

Tags: c++, member-functions, virtual-inheritance

Let's consider the following code snippet:

```
struct A { void f(); };
struct B : virtual A {};
struct C : virtual A {};
struct D : B, C {};
```

What can I say? that `D` has two different member functions `B::A::f` and `C::B::f` which are called over a same object? or they are just aliases of a same member function?

For example, for the non-virtual case,

```
struct A { void f(); };
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : B, C {};
```

`D` has two different member functions `B::A::f` and `C::A::f` because they just have different names, so, calling `D().f()` is an ambigüity because I have to specify to which member I want to call.

However, in the virtual inhericante case, that isn't required anymore because calling by one path or another resolves to call the function over a same object, and I don't know anymore if, in the virtual inheritance case, I have two different member functions which resolves or are executed over a same object, or they are just aliases of a same member function.

Anyway, from a practical point of view that difference doesn't matter, but from a more formal point of view I'm not sure about what to say.

Comment: @Bon In short, I don't know how many function members (without considering the default-generated members) has D.

Comment: you just rediscovered what virtual inheritance is good for :P

Answer (score 2):

In the virtual inheritance case you have `D::A::f()` and no specific overridden versions in the two middle inheritance levels.

`D().B::A::f()` works for the same reason that it works in this straightforward case (it inherits the parent version):

```
struct A { void f(); };
struct B : A {};
struct D : B {};
```

Comment: If that were the case, how does `D().B::A::f()` even compile, if `D` has no such a member function?